# Can you give an example of reentrancy?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, example

What is an example of reentrancy in everyday speech?

Comment: As far as I know, "reentrancy" is only a technical term in computer programming, and is not used at all in everyday speech.

Comment: I was watching a presentation where it was said that "reentrant" structures are present in language when linguists trying to describe how meaning is derived and it's one of the problems of natural language processing. I know reentrant computer programs but I can't come up with an example in english.

Comment: Note: In the light of comments so far. I've edited the question. It can be changed back if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without studying the subject and after a quick Google search, this seems to be an example:

[image]

The above comes from:

**Mapping between English Strings and Reentrant Semantic Graphs**
Fabienne Braune1, Daniel Bauer2, Kevin Knight3 
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.679.6045&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thanks! What was your search query?

Comment: I've forgotten. I started off with *linguistics reentrancy*, then *computational linguistics* and probably ended up with *natural language reentrant*